# Why is text inside div getting hidden?

Tags: javascript, css, html

```js
function clicked(IdClicked) {
  var ElementClicked = document.getElementById(IdClicked);
  ElementClicked.className = ElementClicked.className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden';
}
```

```css
div.hidden {
  height: 500px;
}
div {
  height: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="clicked('homepage'); ">About</span>
. . .
<div id="homepage" class='hidden'>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
</div>
<div id="intro_page">
  <h1 id="intro_page_caption">About Me</h1>
  <p id="intro_main_text">I enjoy reading, swimming, jogging, painting and exploring.</p>
  <figure class="intro_pic1">
      <img src="img/award.jpg" alt="Receiving Award" height="250"/>
    <figcaption>Award 2015</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

The JS function toggles the class from `''` to `hidden` at the click of the button.

Now, the problem is that the `overflow:hidden` makes the text `intro_page_caption` and `intro_main_text` hidden completely at all times.

Also, currently my webpage initially shows both the divs (`homepage` as well as `intro_page`). At the click of the button, `homepage` is hidden and `intro_page` takes its place.

I have already tried changing the height to various values, but it doesn't solve the problem.

I want to achieve two things:

1. The text `intro_page_caption` as well as `intro_main_text` should be visible.
2. `intro_page` should be invisible when `homepage` is visible and vice-versa.

Comment: where is your button that calls the function?

Comment: It would help if you provided enough code to make a working [stack snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/sL2udL89/

Comment: You have to choose between  `visibility: hidden` or `display:none`

Comment: @Dannnno  I have done it now. As you can see, nothing from `intro_page` is visible

Comment: @Abhitalks Thanks a ton! My problem is now clearly visible.

Comment: You are cutting intro_page height with CSS, when should that be visible? On click over 'home page'?

Comment: @AramilRey I'm not sure what you're asking for. Could you re-phrase please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are applying `height: 0px` and the transition to disappear to all the `div`s on the page, including the `div`s with your "about" content. so target just the `#homepage div` with your css

```js
function clicked(IdClicked) {
  var ElementClicked = document.getElementById(IdClicked);
  ElementClicked.className = ElementClicked.className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden';

}
```

```css
#homepage.hidden {
  height: 500px;
}
#homepage {
  height: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="clicked('homepage'); ">About</span>
. . .
<div id="homepage" class='hidden'>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
</div>
<div id="intro_page">
  <h1 id="intro_page_caption">About Me</h1>
  <p id="intro_main_text">I enjoy reading, swimming, jogging, painting and exploring.</p>
  <figure class="intro_pic1">
      <img src="img/award.jpg" alt="Receiving Award" height="250"/>
    <figcaption>Award 2015</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the ternary operator from

```
function clicked(IdClicked) {
  var ElementClicked = document.getElementById(IdClicked);
  ElementClicked.className = ElementClicked.className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden';
}
```

to this

```
function clicked(IdClicked) {
  var ElementClicked = document.getElementById(IdClicked);
  ElementClicked.style.visibility = ElementClicked.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}
```

CSS rules can't be blank, [see visbility rules to set it.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

Comment: You seem to be confusing *className* with *css rule* !

Comment: @Aaronepower : I tried that. It doesn't have any effect on the webpage.

Comment: @Aaronepower : Nope, that also doesn't work. It makes the button completely unresponsive.